# How can I prevent a column break before the first sub-entry in the index?

Tags: page-breaking, indexing, imakeidx

I am writing my indices with imakeidx and I want to use sub-entries as well. As you can see on my image, I am getting a column break which I think is making it more difficult to understand.
Can I control that somehow? Should I?

[image]

**Edit** If I would have "gap", "axial", and "radial" a separation between the last two would not disturb very much. But the split directly after "gap" looks strange.

---

MWE for play-around:

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: makeindex
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
% we don't want a page break before THE FIRST subitem
\makeatletter\renewcommand\subitem{\nobreak\@idxitem\hspace*{20\p@}}\makeatother
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\index{gap!radial}\index{gap!axial}
\index{gapa!radial}\index{gapa!axial}
\index{gapb!radial}\index{gapb!axial}
\index{gapc!radial}\index{gapc!axial}
\index{gapd!radial}\index{gapd!axial}
\index{gap1!radial}\index{gap1!axial}
\index{gapa1!radial}\index{gapa1!axial}
\index{gapb1!radial}\index{gapb1!axial}
\index{gapc1!radial}\index{gapc1!axial}
\index{gapd1!radial}\index{gapd1!axial}
\index{gap2!radial}\index{gap2!axial}
\index{gapa2!radial}\index{gapa2!axial}
\index{gapb2!radial}\index{gapb2!axial}
\index{gapc2!radial}\index{gapc2!axial}
\index{gapd2!radial111}\index{gapd2!axial111}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

The column break should appear before gapd2 or after axial111.

Comment: clearer title: "a sub-entry in the index"

Comment: I'd try with `\makeatletter\renewcommand\subitem{\nobreak\@idxitem\hspace*{20\p@}}\makeatother`

Comment: A shame, but I don't even understand enough of this line to insert the missing `}`. Please help me and I will test it.

Comment: Yes, a closing brace is missing (and `\nobreak` should go after `\@idxitem`): `\renewcommand\subitem{\@idxitem\nobreak\hspace*{20\p@}}`. It's just the original definition with the addition of `\nobreak`.

Comment: Follow-up Question: [Eliminate column balancing on last page of index](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/509513/4301).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The solution is to move `\nobreak` after `\@idxitem`:

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: makeindex
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeatletter
% we don't want a page break before a subitem
\renewcommand\subitem{\@idxitem\nobreak\hspace*{20\p@}}
\makeatother

\makeindex
\begin{document}
\index{gap!radial}\index{gap!axial}
\index{gapa!radial}\index{gapa!axial}
\index{gapb!radial}\index{gapb!axial}
\index{gapc!radial}\index{gapc!axial}
\index{gapd!radial}\index{gapd!axial}
\index{gap1!radial}\index{gap1!axial}
\index{gapa1!radial}\index{gapa1!axial}
\index{gapb1!radial}\index{gapb1!axial}
\index{gapc1!radial}\index{gapc1!axial}
\index{gapd1!radial}\index{gapd1!axial}
\index{gap2!radial}\index{gap2!axial}
\index{gapa2!radial}\index{gapa2!axial}
\index{gapb2!radial}\index{gapb2!axial}
\index{gapc2!radial}\index{gapc2!axial}
\index{gapd2!radial}\index{gapd2!axial}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

The standard definition of `\subitem` is without `\nobreak`; the command `\@idxitem` just does a `\par` and sets `\hangindent`, so if we add the penalty (`\nobreak` is `\penalty 10000`) after it, TeX will not break a page at this point.

---

If you just want that the first subitem remains attached to the main entry, then change the code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` into

```
\makeatletter
% we don't want a page break before the first subitem
\newif\iffirst@subitem
\def\@idxitem{%
  \par\hangindent40\p@ % original
  \first@subitemtrue   % added
}
\def\subitem{%
  \par\hangindent40\p@
  \iffirst@subitem
    \nobreak
    \first@subitemfalse
  \fi
  \hspace*{20\p@}}
\makeatother
```

This will add the penalty only between a main item and the first subitem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working with lengthy index for a textbook. I found it useful implement egreg's suggestion using LaTeX's renewcommand, which I could drop into the preamble. This code also suppresses breaks before first subsubitem and keeps \see entries on the same page.  (The \see fix is somewhat experimental, as I'm not sure it will be appropriate for longer entries, but it does eliminate widows...)

```
    \newif\iffirst@subitem
    \newif\iffirst@subsubitem\first@subsubitemfalse
    \renewcommand\@idxitem{\par\hangindent 40\p@ \first@subitemtrue}
    \renewcommand\subitem{\par\hangindent 
           40\p@\iffirst@subitem\nobreak\first@subitemfalse\fi 
           \hspace*{20\p@}\first@subsubitemtrue}
    \renewcommand\subsubitem{\par\hangindent 
           40\p@\iffirst@subsubitem\nobreak\first@subsubitemfalse\fi 
           \hspace*{30\p@}}
    \renewcommand\see[2]{\samepage\emph{\seename} #1}
```