# why \see and \seealso "overwrites" page number?

Tags: indexing

Why  \see and \seealso overwrites page number?
Can i redefine indexing command to keep page number(s) before `see` output? 
Something like:

```
Cats 1,3,6-7 see also Dog
```

MWE form this site:

```
        \documentclass{article}
        \begin{filecontents*}{test2.xdy}  
        (require "page-ranges.xdy")
        (define-location-class "arabic-page-numbers"
                               ("arabic-numbers") :min-range-length 1)
        (markup-locref :open "\hyperpage{" :close "}")
        \end{filecontents*}
        \usepackage[hyperindex=false]{hyperref}
        \usepackage{index}
        \newindex{testindex}{idx}{idn}{Index}
        \makeindex
        \begin{document}
        Let's discuss letter d\index[testindex]{d}\index[testindex]{letter|see{d}}
        and c.\index[testindex]{c}\index[testindex]{letter|see{c}}

        \newpage
        \printindex[testindex]
        \end{document}
```

p.s.
I need some dictionary like entries, but don't want to use `glossary`, because we need some `glossies` to define before we use it and there can be different definitions depending in contents of use...Actually I need to  some text after page number and `see` command looked promising..

Here is a related question (unanswered) [Put ';' after page number in index](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291844/put-after-page-number-in-index) but this removes `linebrake` in all indexies

Comment: it's not usually considered logical to have a page number on a "see" entry, and often, the term under which it's listed doesn't even appear on the page from which the "see" entry was entered. and for a "see also" entry, it's assumed that there's already at least one page number for the entry so marked.  it would be possible to change these definitions, but it's certainly not traditional.

Comment: Ok, you are right...I did it: once adding index entry and second step adding see entry and it works. Or using patch from linked question works fine...       \renewcommand{\see}{} \index[testindex]{letter!\textit{Therm to define}}
      \index[testindex]{letter!\textit{Therm to define}|see{Therm explanation}}

Comment: As I mentioned patch in linked question redefines subitem for all multiple indexies....can i pass this patch to an one particular index file? I can edit it, but dont like editing index files :)

Comment: Ah the trick is to make another `\index` entry! One for the page number and on for the "see also". That was not so easy for a bear-of-very-little-brain to understand... :(