# Switch on (enable) global hyphenation in Index: in the first line and in \texttt

Tags: memoir, indexing, typewriter, imakeidx, makeindex

`hyphenation{}` does not work in Index in the first line and in \texttt.

How can I switch it on?

How can we prevent `new column` when the hyphenation is switched on?

Only Index settings of hyphenation are preferable.

The problem is discussed on the base of the following MWE:

[Remove (delete) unexpected new line when the word in index is long (hyphenation)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392275/remove-delete-unexpected-new-line-when-the-word-in-index-is-long-hyphenation)

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeindex[program=makeindex,
options=-s myindex.ist,
title={First},
name=first]


%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392783/44348
\usepackage{tempora} %TemporaLGCUni of Times type
\usepackage{newtxmath} %math font of Times type
% need to set the monospace=typewritter font
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213835/using-many-typewriter-fonts-in-a-single-document
\makeatletter %load fonts for cmtt
\providecommand{\EC@ttfamily}[5]{%
    \DeclareFontShape{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{
        <-8.5>#50800
        <8.5-9.5>#50900
        <9.5-10.5>#51000
        <10.5-11.5>#51095
        <11.5-13>#51200
        <13-15.5>#51440
        <15.5-18.5>#51728
        <18.5-22>#52074
        <22-27>#52488
        <27-32>#52986
        <32->#53583}{}}
\DeclareFontFamily{T2A}{cmtt}{\hyphenchar\font\m@ne}
\EC@ttfamily{T2A}{cmtt}{m}{n}{latt}
\EC@ttfamily{T2A}{cmtt}{m}{sl}{last}
\EC@ttfamily{T2A}{cmtt}{m}{it}{lait}
\EC@ttfamily{T2A}{cmtt}{m}{sc}{latc}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{cmtt}{bx}{n}%
{<->ssub*cmtt/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{cmtt}{bx}{it}%
{<->ssub*cmtt/m/it}{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}


%       https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132415/44348
\makeatletter
% we don't want a page break before a subitem
\renewcommand\subitem{\@idxitem\nobreak\hspace*{20\p@}}
\makeatother


%does not work 
%\hyphenation{foofoofoo-foofoofoo-foofoofoo-foofoofoofoofo-ofoofoofoo-foo}
\hyphenation{barbarbar-barbarbarbar-barbarbarbarbarbar-barbarbarbarbar}
\hyphenation{Diag-nos-tic-Tests-Sca-ling-And-In-fer-ring}




\begin{document}
Einstein\index[first]{Einstein\-EinsteinEinstein\-Einstein\-Einstein!NewLine}
Heisenberg\index[first]{Heisenberg} % Person index

\blindtext


barbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbar barbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbar
\blindtext[4]



Einstein\index[first]{Einstein\-EinsteinEinstein\-Einstein\-Einstein!NewLine}
\index[first]{foofoofoofoo\-foofoofoofoofoofoo\-foofoofoofoofoo\-foofoofoo}

\index[first]{barbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbar}

%       \index[first]{algorithm!barbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbar}

%\index[first]{barbarbar\-barbarbarbar\-barbarbarbarbarbar\-barbarbarbarbar}
\index[first]{algorithm!\texttt{DiagnosticTestsScalingAndInferring}} 

\blindtext


\printindex[first] 

\end{document}
```

PDF

[image]

**UDT**

Additional question "How to force word `Newline` after `Einstein` not to go to the next column?" can be solved using this answer
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132415/44348

However with these commands "last" `Einstein` go to the new line.

Comment: Your NewLine is a subitem (because of the `!`). You want to prevent breaks between item and subitem. The answer is here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132415/2388. And please don't ask two questions at once.

Comment: Your text doesn't hyphenate as it is in \texttt. See here about how to enable hyphenation with the typewriter font: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204412/how-to-hyphenate-automatically-within-texttt-when-using-t1-encoding-and-lmodern

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, these questions are connected, because when we add code presented by @greg, local hyphenation force new line in the second column. There is no problem  with `\texttt`, you can comment it if you wish. The problem with `\hyphenation{barbar...}` still take place.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, moreover `\texttt` works fine with local hyphenation `\-`.

Comment: It doesn't matter if there are connected. It is confusing if the title of the question and the text are about different things. Your barbar doesn't hyphenate as it is the first word in a paragraph.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thank you for fixing the problem. How can we `\relax` this requirement?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\@idxitem}{\par\hangindent40\p@\hspace{0pt}\ignorespaces}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to hyphenate monospaced text, load the fonts without `\hyphenchar\font=-1`; in order to allow hyphenation in the first word, modify `\@idxitem` adding `\hspace{0pt}\ignorespaces` at the end.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeindex[program=makeindex,
%options=-s myindex.ist,
title={First},
name=first]


%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392783/44348
\usepackage{tempora} %TemporaLGCUni of Times type
\usepackage{newtxmath} %math font of Times type
% need to set the monospace=typewritter font
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213835/using-many-typewriter-fonts-in-a-single-document
\makeatletter %load fonts for cmtt
\providecommand{\EC@ttfamily}[5]{%
    \DeclareFontShape{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{
        <-8.5>#50800
        <8.5-9.5>#50900
        <9.5-10.5>#51000
        <10.5-11.5>#51095
        <11.5-13>#51200
        <13-15.5>#51440
        <15.5-18.5>#51728
        <18.5-22>#52074
        <22-27>#52488
        <27-32>#52986
        <32->#53583}{}}
\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{cmtt}{}
\DeclareFontFamily{T2A}{cmtt}{}
\EC@ttfamily{T1}{cmtt}{m}{n}{ectt}
\EC@ttfamily{T1}{cmtt}{m}{sl}{ecst}
\EC@ttfamily{T1}{cmtt}{m}{it}{ecit}
\EC@ttfamily{T1}{cmtt}{m}{sc}{ectc}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{cmtt}{bx}{n}%
  {<->ssub*cmtt/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{cmtt}{bx}{it}%
  {<->ssub*cmtt/m/it}{}
\EC@ttfamily{T2A}{cmtt}{m}{n}{latt}
\EC@ttfamily{T2A}{cmtt}{m}{sl}{last}
\EC@ttfamily{T2A}{cmtt}{m}{it}{lait}
\EC@ttfamily{T2A}{cmtt}{m}{sc}{latc}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{cmtt}{bx}{n}%
{<->ssub*cmtt/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{cmtt}{bx}{it}%
{<->ssub*cmtt/m/it}{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}


%       https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132415/44348
\makeatletter
% we want hyphenation also in the first word
\renewcommand{\@idxitem}{\par\hangindent40\p@\hspace{0pt}\ignorespaces}
% we don't want a page break before a subitem
\renewcommand\subitem{\@idxitem\nobreak\hspace*{20\p@}}
\makeatother


%does not work 
%\hyphenation{foofoofoo-foofoofoo-foofoofoo-foofoofoofoofo-ofoofoofoo-foo}
\hyphenation{barbarbar-barbarbarbar-barbarbarbarbarbar-barbarbarbarbar}
\hyphenation{Diag-nos-tic-Tests-Sca-ling-And-In-fer-ring}




\begin{document}
Einstein\index[first]{Einstein\-EinsteinEinstein\-Einstein\-Einstein!NewLine}
Heisenberg\index[first]{Heisenberg} % Person index

\blindtext


barbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbar barbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbar
\blindtext[4]



Einstein\index[first]{Einstein\-EinsteinEinstein\-Einstein\-Einstein!NewLine}
\index[first]{foofoofoofoo\-foofoofoofoofoofoo\-foofoofoofoofoo\-foofoofoo}

\index[first]{barbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbar}

%       \index[first]{algorithm!barbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbar}

%\index[first]{barbarbar\-barbarbarbar\-barbarbarbarbarbar\-barbarbarbarbar}
\index[first]{algorithm!\texttt{DiagnosticTestsScalingAndInferring}} 

\blindtext


\printindex[first] 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks! Special gratitude for enabling `T1` fonts!