# Eliminate column balancing on last page of index

Tags: spacing, indexing, multicol, imakeidx

I am using the solution from [How can I prevent a column break before the first sub-entry in the index?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132415/4301) in my index. However, that has a bad side effect on the last page of the index in that the index entries on the left are vertically spaced:

[image]

How do I eliminate this excess spacing?

### Code: A

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

%% Adapted from dapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130169/4301

\makeatletter
% we don't want a page break before a subitem
\renewcommand\subitem{\@idxitem\nobreak\hspace*{20\p@}}
\makeatother

\makeindex

\begin{document}
Some text
\index{gap!radial}\index{gap!axial}
\index{gapa!radial}\index{gapa!axial}
\index{gapb!radial}\index{gapb!axial}
\index{gapc!radial}\index{gapc!axial}
\index{gapd!radial}\index{gapd!axial}
\index{gap1!radial}\index{gap1!axial}
\index{gapa1!radial}\index{gapa1!axial}
\index{gapb1!radial}\index{gapb1!axial}
\index{gapc1!radial}\index{gapc1!axial}
\index{gapd1!radial}\index{gapd1!axial}
\index{gap2!radial}\index{gap2!axial}
\index{gapa2!radial}\index{gapa2!axial}
\index{gapb2!radial}\index{gapb2!axial}
\index{gapc2!radial}\index{gapc2!axial}
\index{gapd2!radial}\index{gapd2!axial}
\index{gap2!radial 1}\index{gap2!axial 1}
\index{gapa2!radial 1}\index{gapa2!axial 1}
\index{gapb2!radial 1}\index{gapb2!axial 1}
\index{gapc2!radial 1}\index{gapc2!axial 1}
\index{gapd2!radial 1}\index{gapd2!axial 1}
\index{gap2!radial 2}\index{gap2!axial 2}
\index{gapa2!radial 2}\index{gapa2!axial 2}
\index{gapb2!radial 2}\index{gapb2!axial 2}
\index{gapc2!radial 2}\index{gapc2!axial 2}
\index{gapd2!radial 2}\index{gapd2!axial 2}
\index{gap2!radial 3}\index{gap2!axial 3}
\index{gapa2!radial 3}\index{gapa2!axial 3}
\index{gapb2!radial 3}\index{gapb2!axial 3}
\index{gapc2!radial 3}\index{gapc2!axial 3}
\index{gapd2!radial 3}\index{gapd2!axial 3}
\index{gap2!radial 4}\index{gap2!axial 4}
\index{gapa2!radial 4}\index{gapa2!axial 4}
\index{gapb2!radial 4}\index{gapb2!axial 4}
\index{gapc2!radial 4}\index{gapc2!axial 4}
\index{gapd2!radial 4}\index{gapd2!axial 4}
\index{gap2!radial 5}\index{gap2!axial 5}
\index{gapa2!radial 5}\index{gapa2!axial 5}
\index{gapb2!radial 5}\index{gapb2!axial 5}
\index{gapc2!radial 5}\index{gapc2!axial 5}
\index{gapd2!radial 5}\index{gapd2!axial 5}
\index{gap2!radial 6}\index{gap2!axial 6}
\index{gapa2!radial 6}\index{gapa2!axial 6}
\index{gapb2!radial 6}\index{gapb2!axial 6}
\index{gapc2!radial 6}\index{gapc2!axial 6}
\index{gapd2!radial 6}\index{gapd2!axial 6}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\raggedcolumns\printindex` ?

Comment: If you don’t mind having the last page printed as a single column, you may use `\usepackage[unbalanced=true]{idxlayout}` in the preamble. It depends on how many entries there are on the last page. If there are only ten or twelve, this would be ok (for me, at least!).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\raggedcolumns\printindex`

Comment: Unfortunately, this effects all pages -- the other pages also don't have the columns balanced. While it is acceptable for the particular document I am working on, just wondering if there was a better solution to only apply this to the last page.  Forced to wait 7minutes before accepting!!!

Comment: @PeterGrill possibly you want to make it use `multicolumn*` to stop balancing I may look later (but I may not) don't accept, someone else may answer, perhaps egreg has read the imakeidx manual, you never know:-)